# cronJob on windows

Tags: windows

i wanna to create a cron job on windows that daily delete files from a specific folder.

how can i do this??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Use Schedule tasks in windows. Check [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569). You can use [del](http://www.computerhope.com/delhlp.htm) command to remove one or more files. Put it inside a batch script and schedule it as a task.

Answer (score 3):

You want [Scheduled Tasks](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569).

> With Scheduled Tasks, you can schedule
>   any script, program, or document to
>   run at a time that is most convenient
>   for you. Scheduled Tasks starts every
>   time that you start Windows XP and
>   runs in the background, and it starts
>   each task that you schedule at the
>   time that you specify when you create
>   the task.

Edit your question if you specifically need help with the deleting files bit, but typing in `help del` at a command prompt should tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: how to allow it to delete files daily.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Write a batch script that invokes `del` on the files you want to delete, and use Scheduled Tasks to set it to run daily.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Cron for Windows](http://www.kalab.com/freeware/cron/cron.htm),
 it's very easy to use if you are familiar with cron from *nix